# about CppWinRT internal 3

Tags: cppwinrt

What is the use case of `composable_factory`? It seems it is related to `m_outer`, but I can not find any code calling it (Searched all files in the cppwinrt directory). Many thanks!!!

Comment: Have you read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system)?

Comment: Based on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system#composable-activation), it mentions a composition factory interface is used to create composable instances of the class. A composable factory interface declares zero or more composable factory methods that can be used to activate instances of the class for composition purposes. Note that it is legal to have a composable factory interface with zero factory methods. This implies that the class can be used for composition, but that third-parties may not directly compose the class.

Answer (score 0):

composable_factory is used for constructing types that allow inheritance. In the Windows Runtime, since base class and derived classes may be in separate components, or even written in separate languages, they use COM aggregation to stitch the base and derived classes together into what appears to be, to the client, a single object. A good example of this would be if you created your own MyButton class that is not sealed / final. It would both compose with Button and be derivable by other classes.

Much like activation_factory, composable_factory serves as a specialized activation factory for instantiating objects while taking a base class to derive from during construction. You can see how that fits together with the inner & outer args here:

https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/c36cf05f5030726c8ada1b89fc78bd470f737032/strings/base_composable.h

I believe m_outer is typically the base class, and inner is the derived.

Ben

Comment: "I believe m_outer is typically the base class, and inner is the derived", No, I think the m_outer is the derived class and m_inner is the base class. Take ```Windows.UI.Xaml.Application``` as an example, when we declare something like ```struct App : ApplicationT<App>{...}```, we are deriving ```App``` from ```Application``` and ```App.m_inner``` will be a reference to ```Application```. In this example, ```App``` is composing but not composed and ```App.m_outer``` does not exist. ```Application``` is composed and will hold a reference to ```App``` as its ```outer```.